# Microsoft Visual Linking Forms/Projects

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So I have one Solution with four Projects in it. In `Project_Owner_Add` I want a `Next` button so that when it is clicked one of the other Projects is displayed.

This is my code.

```
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Project_Owner_Add.Form1 next = Project_Owner_Add_Product_Owner.Form1();
    next.Show();
}
```

The error message is as follows:

> Project_Owner_Add_Product_Owner does not exist in the current context

I'm assuming I'm going about calling information from a separate Project all wrong but I had sort of thought it was a matter of simply linking the forms together (this also doesn't work).

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Have you added the appropriate using and reference to the Project?

Comment: Just gave that a go but now I'm getting a slightly different error message: "Non-invocable member 'Form1' cannot be used as a method." Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to your other project as already suggested, also you can use `using` directive to set some alias for your `Form1` class in case when it exists in both projects.

The keyword `new` is essential when it comes to instantiating classes in C#. You can do something like this :

Add reference to other project if needed - > then :

```
using MyForm = Project_Owner_Add.Form1;

private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyForm next = new MyForm();
    next.Show();
}
```

Comment: Using your answer and the other guys answer I got it to work. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the second project. Do the following steps:

- Right click `Project_Owner_Add` and select `Add Reference`.
- Then `Solution --> Projects` and select second project from the list.

Then try this:

```
secondprojectNamespace.Form1 next = new secondprojectNamespace.Form1();
next.Show();
```

Comment: Got it going. Thanks again.:)