# Type or namespace could not be found error

Tags: c#, namespaces

Right now, I am linking two projects with a use of a button.
I have Employee Registration Form and List of Employees.
I already did "Add Existing Project" which is the List of Employees. I also did the "Add Reference" (List of Employees).

I inserted this code into a button on Employee Registration in order to see the List of Employees form

```
private void button_view_emp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List_Employees.list_emp list = new List_Employees.list_emp(); 
   this.Hide();
   list.Show();
}
```

It displays the List of Employees Form.

The List of Employees form has a Back Button. And if I will click it, it should return again to the Employee Registration Form.

I inserted this code on the back button:

```
private void button_back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frm_employee_registration.FormEmployee_Reg ff = new frm_employee_registration.FormEmployee_Reg();
   this.Hide();   
}
```

But it gives me an error of

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'frm_employee_registration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\List_Employees\List_Employees\list_emp.cs   159 13  List_Employees

I double- checked the spelling of the namespaces and it matches.
Why is that it connects smoothly from Employee Registration to the List of Employees? But if I do it the other way around, it gets an error?

Comment: Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: are you miss a `namespace` in one of the classes.. can you show the class header of the `list_emp.cs` file right click on the project properties and make sure that all of the `.cs` files have that default namespace name in the file(s) you need to show what the class header using all the way  to the `namespace { }` looks like so we can see what you see

Comment: Take a look at this question may helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847998/microsoft-visual-linking-forms-projects